# Call JavaScript function from ASP.NET Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am writing Razor code in a view, and need to call a JavaScript function with the JSON that is rendered by the Razor code:

```
// JavaScript function
function buildTemplate(currentTemplate) {
    alert('hello world');
}

@* Build out entire Template structure in JavaScript *@
@foreach (Template template in Model.Templates)
{            
    buildTemplate(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(template));        
}
```

For some reason, Razor thinks that `buildTemplate` is a C# method it can't find, and it errors out.

Has anyone done this before?  Any advice?

Thanks,

Philip

Comment: Could you not write buildTemplate as a razor helper method using the syntax @helper buildTemplate. You could assign the output to a texbox then read the contents in Jscript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use

```
@: buildTemplate(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(template));
```

or

```
<text>
buildTemplate(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(template));
</text>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `<script>` Tags

```
@* Build out entire Template structure in JavaScript *@
@foreach (Template template in Model.Templates)
{            
    <script>buildTemplate(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(template))</script>        
}
```

I have not tested this Code